# How to add title, snippet and icon to ClusterItem? InfoWindows

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I hope you can help me with this error. I have a Map with a several markers. Before implement Cluster Markers, I could show a infoWindows with title and custom icons but now with Cluster Markers I didn't know how to do that.

I read a several articles but I can't fix that. If anybody know what I'm doing wrong, please help..

Here's my code.

AsynTask where I populate the map with markers

```
class AllAlojamientos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsV2General.this.getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait a moment.");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_todos_alojamientos, "GET", params);

            try{
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    alojamiento = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALOJAMIENTO);

                } else {
                    //
                }

            } catch (JSONException e){
                pDialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String a) {
        super.onPostExecute(a);
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try{

                for (int i = 0; i < alojamiento.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = alojamiento.getJSONObject(i);

                    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LATITUD)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LONGITUD)))).title(c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE))
                            .snippet(c.getString(TAG_DIRECCION))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.home)));
                    marker.showInfoWindow();

                    //Default LatLng Santiago
                    String latitud = "-33.495542";
                    String longitud= "-70.662749";

                    // Move Camera 
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitud),
                                        Double.parseDouble(longitud))).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
                    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);

                    double latitudItem = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LATITUD));
                    double longitudItem = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LONGITUD));

                    clusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer(getActivity(), googleMap, clusterManager));

                    MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(latitudItem, longitudItem);
                    clusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);


                }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And here is MyItem Class

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
  private final LatLng mPosition;
  private String mTitle;

  BitmapDescriptor icon;
  String snippet;

  public MyItem(double lat, double lng){
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
  }

  @Override
  public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
  }

  public String getTitle(){
    return  mTitle;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title){
    mTitle = title;
  }

}
```

Comment: You may need to change your MyItem class and add more variables such as snippet and icon. Did you try that?

Comment: If you want to custom the `InfoWindows`, please take look at [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android). To make a Cluster marker you can use google map utils [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).